# Replace comma, dash, and enter key in textarea with space

Tags: javascript, keycode

I want that when user presses a comma, dash, or enter key, the textarea replace will show a space.

This code only works for the enter key.

```js
    $("#site_name").on("keypress",function(e) {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if ((key == 188)||(key == 13)||(key == 173)||(key == 191)) {
            document.getElementById("site_name").value=document.getElementById("site_name").value + " ";
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  name="site_name" id="site_name" style="width: 100%;" rows="3"> </textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to continue to use a JavaScript event I would suggest using the `keydown` event.  `keydown` and `keypress` will give you different results as they map to different functionality.  Comma = 188, dash = 189, enter = 13.

```js
$("#site_name").on("keydown",function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    console.log("keycode: " + key);
    if ((key == 189)||(key == 188)||(key == 13)||(key == 173)||(key == 191))              
    {    
        document.getElementById("site_name").value=document.getElementById("site_name").value + " ";
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  name="site_name" id="site_name" style="width: 100%;" rows="3"> </textarea>
```

Comment: @HristiyanDodov he didn't mention periods in his question *comma or dash or enter in textarea*

Comment: Yep, my bad, sorry.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. your answer is worked for me.:))))

Answer (score 0):

This uses regex. I replaced the `keypress` event with `keyup` since `keypress` is activated *before* the actual character is added, so the comma/dash/linebreak can't be removed immediately. You can revert it to `keypress` if you actually want this behavior.

```js
$("#site_name").on("keyup", function() {
  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[\,\-\n]/g, " "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea name="site_name" id="site_name" style="width: 100%;" rows="3"></textarea>
```

The `g` in `/[\,\-\n]/g` indicates that the global flag is used. That's needed to replace *all* occurrences of the desired characters. If this flag is not used and you copy-paste a bunch of commas and dashes, only the first one would get replaced. More on regex [here](https://regexone.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change `keyCode` to `which`

`var key = e.which;`

Comment: @miken32 because he is using `keypress` which will return a `0` for most keys where `which` will return the character value.

Comment: here is a great site for testing key presses and why you should use `.which` http://www.west-wind.com/westwindwebtoolkit/samples/ajax/html5andcss3/keycodechecker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try `45` & `44` keycodes instead:

```js
$("#site_name").on("keypress",function(e) {
    var key = e.keyCode;
    console.log(key);
    if ((key == 45)||(key == 13)||(key == 44)||(key == 191)) {
        document.getElementById("site_name").value=document.getElementById("site_name").value + " ";

        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  name="site_name" id="site_name" style="width: 100%;" rows="3"> </textarea>
```